# Is the entropy a Lorentz invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, entropy, relativity

So this is the pure question that came into my mind right now.

Is the entropy a Lorentz invariant?

How does the entropy of a gas behaves, when for example it's accelerated at $v = \frac{c}{2}$ or more?

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83488/

Comment: Open access paper: "Proving the Lorentz Invariance of the Entropy and the Covariance of Thermodynamics" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-021-00518-w

Answer (score 7):

According to: G Ares de Parga, B López-Carrera and F Angulo-Brown 
Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, Volume 38, Number 13 2005
"A proposal for relativistic transformations in thermodynamics" entropy is an invariant (which given that entropy is a measure of the accessible states is perhaps reasonable). However, the authors argue more formally that the entropy is invariant if you wish to keep form invariance of thermodynamics. However, they do point out that a "general consensus about this matter has not been reached".

Have a look [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/38/13/001).

Comment: Thank you very much for the article. I want to make it public for eventual future readers, so here is the link for the download.

http://speedy.sh/cT4Sa/parga2005.pdf

Comment: I assume there is some caveat about whether one refers to an extensive or non-extensive system here?